# jQuery doubling up root path on a load() function

Tags: jquery, function, url, load

Why is my root path being doubled up in this function?

```js
function bodyClass(id) {
   var catName = $('#location').children().eq(4).text(),
      rootPar = ("http://localhost/site/" + catName),
      banner = $('#wantedDiv'),
       
      // this load variable doubles up the root path and does not escape the first single quote 
      content = $('<div />').load("'" + rootPar + " " + banner + "'", function(){ 
         $('#placeDiv').prepend(content.html());
      });
      
      // console logging retrieves the correct path inclusing the added "catName"
      console.log(rootPar);

}
bodyClass();
```

Here's what the browser console shows me:

> console.log: http://localhost/site/page
>
> load() func: GET http://localhost/site/'http://localhost/site/page'
>   404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

When the page loads, it will load to `http://localhost/site/` so by adding the root webpage again it will append it to what is already there. I would just add the `catName` to instead of the `rootPar`

Comment: I already tried doing that with no luck. this is the error I get GET http://localhost/site/'Page/ 404 (Not Found) -> still not escaping that first single quote.

Comment: what happens if you remove the single quotes altogether?

Comment: I get a different error -> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]'

Comment: Ok, so if I do this is passes/works -> .load(rootPar + '  ' + '#wantedDiv', function(){... -> I just need to figure out how to call the ID variable instead of the actual ID name.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...for anyone looking for a similar solution.
Just moved the concatenation to the variables and not inside the load() function.

```js
function bodyClass(id) {
   var catName = $('#location').children().eq(4).text(),
      rootPar = (catName + "/ "),
      banner = "'" + '#' + 'wantedDiv' + "'",
      content = $('<div />').load(rootPar + banner, function(){ 
         $('#placeDiv').prepend(content.html());
      });

}
bodyClass();
```